# Where is the data studio report saved?

Tags: report, store, looker-studio

I am using Data stduio.
Where is the created data stduio report saved? Not the data source.

- Not even in Google Drive.
- It doesn't seem to be saved in GCP either.
- You can only find the report list at https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/navigation/reporting.

For security I need to know the repository of the report.